# Problem with uninstalling virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

I downloaded from virtualbox.org the virtualbox package `4.2.4*.deb`.

I wanted to install it with `dpkg -i` and terminal requested me to use command alien instead.

So I did `alien <package>` then `dpkg -i <package>` and used virtualbox.

Now I want to uninstall virtualbox (because something went wrong) because it was not installed with `sudo apt-get install`.

I want to use command `dpkg -e <package>` or `dpkg --purge <package>` but this ends with report

```
file or directory not found
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
```

reports:

```
ii  virtualbox-4.2                                  4.2.4-81684~Ubuntu~quantal                     amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
rc  virtualbox-qt                                   4.1.18-dfsg-1ubuntu1.1                         amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

what should I do next ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2 virtualbox-qt
```

That should remove them both.

Comment: thank you ! I was blind !

of course

sudo apt-get purge virtualbox

is not sufficient and so system does not know which package.

sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2 virtualbox-qt

is the solution !

Comment: Glad to know it works! Could you mark it as the correct answer then?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*`, which should also remove both.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
sudo apt-get --remove purge virtualbox-4.2 virtualbox-qt
```

Comment: moin. yes this is more correct ... thx. that was a while ago. Til later.

Answer (score 1):

I also had run like this

`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-\*`

But was not removing completely

To me following worked (Was trying this on Ubuntu 15.10 and Oracle Virtualbox 5.x)

`dpkg -l | grep virtualbox`

which listed as below

`# dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
ii virtualbox-5.0:i386 5.0.12 104815~Ubuntu~wily i386 Oracle VM VirtualBox`

Then i used the command

`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.0:i386`