# I can't uninstall Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: apt, virtualbox, oracle, software-uninstall

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (64bits).

I've downloaded Oracle VirtualBox 6.1 from "virtualbox.org" and installed it. After some time I decided to install its extension pack (also from the same site), to run a machine that needed it.

Then, my computer started to boot really slow, so I was searching forums to fix that but I couldn't. I noticed that "vboxdrv.service" was taking a lot of time to load, but I couldn't deactivate it.

Searching and trying to boost up my booting time, I deleted the extension pack of VirtualBox from the "preferences" of the aplication, because I thought it was the problem but it didn't work, and still boot slow.

Now, I want to delete the whole aplication (without removing the HDDs of my VMs) and reinstall VirtualBox from the Ubuntu repositories, so see if that solve the issue. But the problem is that I can't uninstall it.

I followed this posts:

- [Askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190004/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-in-12-04/190053#190053)
- [Askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223406/problem-with-uninstalling-virtualbox?rq=1)
- [Askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911032/uninstalling-virtualbox) (this one says that could uninstall it but doesn't say how)
- [Oracle VirtualBox FAQ](https://oracle-virtualbox.net/faq/20-how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-on-ubuntu.html)

Running this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-6.1:amd64
```

Output:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  libqt5opengl5 libsdl-ttf2.0-0
Utilice «sudo apt autoremove» para eliminarlos.
Los siguientes paquetes se ELIMINARÁN:
  virtualbox-6.1*
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 1 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
Se liberarán 216 MB después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] S
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 211142 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Desinstalando virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.0-135406~Ubuntu~bionic) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete virtualbox-6.1 (--remove):
 instalado virtualbox-6.1 paquete pre-removal guión el subproceso devolvió un error con estado de salida 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 virtualbox-6.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
```

Output:

```
ii  virtualbox-6.1                             6.1.0-135406~Ubuntu~bionic                      amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

Someone could help me with this?

**EDIT:**

Trying to do this (first output):

```
There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

I get a problem when trying to run "/sbin/vboxconfig". It was due to the Secure Boot, I have to sign the kernel modules first so they can run well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by temporarily disabling my UEFI Secure Boot in the BIOS, instead of signing the kernel modules.

Then I could uninstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-6.1:amd64
```

And everything went OK. Then, I enabled my Secure Boot again.
(If you want to know, It didn't solved my boot time)